Help to identify a book on the history of probability
I'm looking for a very specific book about the history of probability that someone told me about ages ago.
This book was trying to answer the question: Why did probability theory develop so late? Euclid axiomatized geometry some time around 300 BCE but we only get a real discussion of probability as such with Laplace around 1750. Why did this take so long when folks have been gambling since ever?
I'm not asking for a critique of their premise, I just want to remember what the book was.

Have you looked at Todhunter’s book?

Yes I should have mentioned that, thanks for bring it up -- I don't think it's the one I'm looking for.

@DanielShapero The goal of comments is to prompt the author of a question to make edits to that question.  Since you have commented that you consulted the indicated book, it would be good to edit that into the question.

For interested readers, Todhunter's book ("History of the mathematical theory of probability") is referenced here

A while back I read and enjoyed Franklin's "The Science of Conjecture: Evidence and Probability before Pascal".  As I recall it is very much a history book not a math book.

Todhunter's book is freely available at: (A) Internet Archive (copy 1 & copy 2 & copy 3 & several more copies). (B) Google Books (copy 1 & copy 2 & copy 3 & several more copies). (C) Also at "Wikimedia Commons", and probably other places.

I'd suggest Ian Hacking's Emergence of Probability: A Philosophical Study of Early Ideas about Probability, Induction, and Statistical Inference (see the link to freely available Internet Archive copy of its first edition).
Apart from other aspects, the following excerpt (from its second edition pp.1-2) seems relevant to the description in the question:

Probability has two aspects. It is connected with the degree of belief
warranted by evidence, and it is connected with the tendency,
displayed by some chance devices, to produce stable relative
frequencies. Neither of these aspects was self-consciously and
deliberately apprehended by any substantial body of thinkers before
the time of Pascal. There have been several tentative explanations of
this fact. I shall describe them briefly here, but we shall see that
none of them is at all satisfactory.
First, let us run through some quite well-known facts and conjectures
about the prehistory of randomness. Since gambling is ancient and
possibly primeval we expect early ideas of probability. In her
engaging book on the history of this subject, F. N. David [1962]
speculates that gambling may be a first invention of human society.
Her clue to this is the talus. This most common randomizer of ancient
times, is a predecessor of the die: the astragalus or talus is the
‘knucklebone’ or heel bone of a running animal. In creatures such as
deer, horse, oxen, sheep, and hartebeest this bone is so formed that
when it is thrown to land on a level surface it can come to rest in
only four ways. Well-polished and often engraved examples are
regularly found on the sites of ancient Egypt. Tomb illustrations and
scoring boards make it virtually certain that these were used for
gaming.
Similar sheep-like tali begin to occur on Sumerian and Assyrian sites.
Well-polished, oft-used knucklebones are found even in Paleolithic
dwellings. But, unlike the Sumerian sheep bones, these are misleading.
A casual glance at a photograph makes them seem just like Egyptian
tali, but in real life they are enormous, the heel bones of oxen or
larger beasts. The more slender part of these large bones is an
unmistakable handle, and the blunt end a natural hammerhead. We have
no need to imagine these are the mighty dice of debauched and giant
cavemen. They are tools. We have no evidence of possible gambling
devices before the Sumerian and Assyrian sites, and no proof before
Egypt. That is old enough.
It seems to follow that empirical frequencies and averages should be
as old as the rolling of such ancient bones. Nor were tali the only
randomizers. Deciding by lot is familiar from the Talmud, from which
A. M. Hasofer [1967] has recently dug a little probability arithmetic.
Nor can we suppose that gambling was the invention of a single people
who passed it on to their cultural heirs. In one of the very first
books of probability theory, Pierre Rémond de Montmort (1708, p. xii)
works out the probability laws of some pastimes that Jesuit
missionaries found current among seventeenth-century Huron. And so on:
it is hard to find a place where people use no randomizers. Yet
theories of frequency, betting, randomness, and probability appear
only recently. No one knows why. We can canvass a few of the proposed
answers.

It should be remarked that Hacking's narrative does not follow on with ancient times, for, as Jeffrey Barnouw succinctly puts it in his review of the book, the contemporary conception of probability does not extend that far into the past:

Probability in the specific sense proper to probability theory came
into being, in Hacking’s view, in the early 1660s. The concluding
section of the Port Royal Logic, or the Art of Thinking (1662) is the
first distinct landmark in its emergence, but parallel developments in
the work of Christian Huygens, Pascal, Leibniz, Petty, Wilkins, Hudde,
and de Witt (Dutch statesmen concerned with the actuarial basis of
national annuities) and John Graunt (who published “the first
extensive set of statistical inferences drawn from mortality records”
in 1662) suggest that the time was ready for the idea. An important
aspect of Hacking’s masterfully presented argument is devoted to this
phenomenon of “emergence”: why the modern idea of probability
crystallized at this point and could not have earlier. Thus the first
chapters trace the “preconditions” of its emergence, an approach in
intellectual history which Hacking opposes to the search for
“precursors” or “anticipations” (cf. pp. 9, 17, 44, 178).

Another notable book (as mentioned also by Hacking) is Games, Gods and Gambling: The History of Probability from the Earliest Times to the Newtonian Era by Florence N. David. However, it's more a chronography of the development of the early modern conception than an investigation of the underlying motives.
In this connection, I wish to note also Jan von Plato's Creating Modern Probability: Its Mathematics, Physics and Philosophy in Historical Perspective which focuses on the modern conception of probability and its progress in mathematics and physics (less on its philosophical course).

Very interesting and well structured answer.

Thank you, very pleased to hear that.

I wonder whether people understood that they were generating randomness when they threw tali. I am reasonably confident that augury, casting lots on the Bible, or performing the ukei rite, were attempts to ascertain the will of a deity. I may be uncertain about what a particular deity wants, but presumably the deity knows.

@SimonCrase Indeed, but the only way to learn the will of a deity, is by chance.


Why did this take so long when folks have been gambling since ever?

According to Leonard Mlodinow, in The drunkard's walk: How randomness rules our lives, Cardano  wrote The Book on Games of Chance during the 16th century, but it was not published until after Cardano's death. Why delay publication? Cardano's work on probability had financed his university studies; he worked out the odds of various games, which he played with students who had fatter purses, but more slender wits. Why give away his money making secret? By Laplace's time scientists could gain status by publishing.
(Also, Cardano's contemporaries might not have appreciated the difference between calculating odds, and good old fashioned cheating).
